# How do i set a null value on public enum in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

my public enum is:

```
public enum IntervalIncrFreq {
        
        @JsonProperty("1")
        ONE,

        @JsonProperty("2")
        TWO,

        @JsonProperty("4")
        FOUR,

        @JsonProperty("6")
        SIX,

        @JsonProperty("8")
        EIGHT,

        @JsonProperty("12")
        TWELVE
    }
```

I would like to add an empty field, and trying this I had an error:

```
    @JsonProperty("")
    EMPTY,
```

How should i declare the JsonProperty empty?

Comment: What would be the use of that `EMPTY` value for the enum? Why not just use `IntervalIncrFreq  empty = null`? Is this mean to be a default value for (de)serialization?

Comment: Do you want it to work with empty string "", with null values, or with an inexistent property field? Or all of them?

Comment: I want an empty string like -> ""

Answer (score 1):

Writing `@JsonProperty("abc")` is an alias for `@JsonProperty(value = "abc")`. According to [Jackson's (2.6) documentation for the value field](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#value())

> If value is empty String (which is the default), will try to use name of the field that is annotated

Jackson will interpret the empty String parameter to mean that you want the JSON value to use the default name of the field instead, and it would change it to the default name. Here is an example.

```
enum Temp {
    
    @JsonProperty("Apple")
    A,
    
    @JsonProperty("")
    B;

}

class Example
{

    Temp a = Temp.A;
    Temp b = Temp.B;

}

/** That would give you JSON like this */

{

    "a":"Apple"
    "b":"B"

}
```

I think the best way you can accomplish what you want to do would be to do something like this.

`@JsonProperty(" ")`